How did Axler assume $T^2+bT+cI = 0$?
The following result comes from Linear Algebra Done Right, $4$th edition, Sheldon Axler:

Suppose $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{R}$ and $V$ is finite-dimensional. Suppose also that $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $b, c \in \mathbf{R}$ with $b^2 < 4c$. Then $\text{dim null}(T^2+bT+cI)$ is an even number.

Axler starts the proof by the following:

Recall that $\text{null}(T^2+bT+cI)$ is invariant under $T$ (by $5.18$). By replacing $V$ with $\text{null}(T^2+bT+cI)$ and replacing $T$ with $T$ restricted to $\text{null}(T^2+bT+cI)$, we can assume that $T^2+bT+cI = 0$.

My question is, how can we assume $T^2+bT+cI = 0$?
I tried filling in the steps to get to that point, but I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct. Could someone take a look at my reasoning below?

Let $q \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})$ be a monic polynomial defined by $q(x) = x^2+bx+c$. This implies that $q(T) = T^2+bT+cI$. We want to show $q(T) = 0$ to match Axler.
We have that $\text{null} \ q(T) = \{v \in V : q(T)(v) = 0\}$. Thus, if we restrict the space of $q(T)$ to its null space, that is, define $q(T)|_{\text{null} \ q(T)}$ by
$$q(T)|_{\text{null} \ q(T)}(v) = q(T)(v)$$
for all $v \in \text{null} \ q(T)$, then we have $q(T)|_{\text{null} \ q(T)} = 0$. But we know that $\text{null} \ q(T)$ is invariant under $T$, implying that
$$
q(T)|_{\text{null} \ q(T)} = q(T|_{\text{null} \ q(T)}) = 0
$$

However, Axler somehow claims that $q(T) = 0$, whereas I only have $q(T|_{\text{null} \ q(T)}) = 0$, so not sure what is going on.

The null space of an operator is by definition where it equals zero.  So restricting to the null space means restricting to where it is zero.

No, Axler does not claim that $T^2+bT+cI=0$. He just assumes it to write the proof with less notation.
If you don't like it, let $S$ be $T$ restricted to $\text{null}(T^2+bT+cI)$. Then $S^2+bS+cI=0$ and you can continue with the proof.

Got it, thank you! So, what is the purpose of the first line in his proof: "Recall that $\text{null}(T^2+bT+cI)$ invariant under $T$"? Why is that important for what comes next?

@PaulAsh If $W$ is an invariant subspace under $T$, then the "restriction of $T$ to $W$" in this context is the map from $W$ to $W$ given by $w \mapsto Tw$. This only makes sense if $W$ is invariant under $T$.

By replacing V with null$(T^2+bT+cI)$, this Means here our V is null$(T^2+bT+cI)$ and for any $v \in V$, $$T^2(v)+bT(v)+cI(v)=0$$
Because $v \in null(T^2+bT+cI)$

Thanks for your answer!
